# What is lighting up Space Shuttle Endeavour's main engines?

Tags: rocket-science

Al Jazeera has [a terrific collection of Space Shuttle photos](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/inpictures/2011/07/2011721104750892640.html). In [photo #11](http://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2011/7/21/2011721104410294734_19.jpg) we can see something bright in each [Space Shuttle Main Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Main_Engine) (SSME) as [Endeavour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Endeavour) lands. What might that be? A reflection off the back of the combustion chamber? Something related to the [auxiliary power units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_power_unit#Spacecraft) (APUs) venting through the SSMEs?

Here's a smaller cropped version; see the ["photo #11"](http://www.aljazeera.com/mritems/Images/2011/7/21/2011721104410294734_19.jpg) link for the original.

[image: Endeavour landing]

Comment: left over propellant in the plumbing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see in this shot from [a Gizmodo article](http://gizmodo.com/5515374/space-shuttles-engines-are-shower-heads-from-hell) the injector at the centre of the engine is quite reflective.

I assume that it is this catching the spotlights illuminating the shuttle that we can see in that shot.

[image: Injector Nozzle on SSME from Gizmodo.]

Comment: Yep, seems logical.

Comment: Ha... Ha... Ha... So simple!